# Accessing Javascript function from angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, function

```
window.variablename = (function(){
    var fun = myfunction()
});
```

This is my code in main.js in the assets folder. I am trying to access it from angular .ts file. I am able to access when I just declare this inner function globally from .ts file. And I don't know how to access this. Can someone please help me how to access this function for the following code.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a file JS file into assets folder, and consume it from your TS file.

E.g.

> assets/utils.js

```
function displayGreeting(name) {
 console.log('Hello ' + name);
}
```

> TS file

```
import '../assets/utils.js';
declare const displayGreeting: any;

export class MyClass {
 static sayHello() {
  new displayGreeting('World');
 }
}
```

The const nay in your TypeScript file should be the same than your function name in your JS file.
And also you should declare a new instance of the same when you want use it.

Comment: Sometimes, you don't need to specify a relative path for your assets directory depending on your webpack config.